# AWS Connect - Lex Bot Integration Delays

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Amazon Web Services Lex bot connected in an AWS Connect contact flow, but am experiencing 4-5 second delays each time I respond to the bot.

When using the text demo in AWS lex, the reply is immediate, leading me to believe it is related to the Connect speech-to-text parsing algorithm.

Any help determining the cause of this delay or reducing it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found that changing the timeout period in the DTMF section of the 'Customer input' contact flow block to three seconds before switching back to lex and saving helped.

It appears that even though the options in the contact flow block appear as LEX OR DTMF, if you change the settings in DTMF and then revert back to Lex the settings are applied to Lex also.

Comment: How did you solve this timeout issue in Amazon lex? Because setting the DTMF timeout to 20 seconds didn't solve the problem